# Spring AMQP connecting to cluster with LB DNS - use single or multiple addresses?

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-cluster

My code will try to connect to an CloudAMQP 3-node cluster, which provides 2 flavours of DNS names:

1. A record that returns 3 IP addresses.
2. Three records that returns each of the underlying IP address.
   Example:

```
PS C:\Users\LiuSean> nslookup funny-plum-koala.rmq2.cloudamqp.com
...

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    funny-plum-koala.rmq2.cloudamqp.com
Addresses:  3.218.133.71
          34.231.176.151
          44.192.12.180

PS C:\Users\LiuSean> nslookup funny-plum-koala-02.rmq2.cloudamqp.com
...

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    funny-plum-koala-02.rmq2.cloudamqp.com
Address:  3.218.133.71

PS C:\Users\LiuSean> nslookup funny-plum-koala-03.rmq2.cloudamqp.com
...

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    funny-plum-koala-03.rmq2.cloudamqp.com
Address:  34.231.176.151
```

Per Spring AMQP document https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#cluster, it seems that the preferred way is to use the individual names:

```
@Bean
public CachingConnectionFactory ccf() {
   CachingConnectionFactory ccf = new CachingConnectionFactory();
   ccf.setAddresses("host1:5672,host2:5672,host3:5672");
   return ccf;
}
```

But does this offer benefits over using the single DNS records that returns 3 addresses?
I've done my share of searching but there doesn't seem to be a definitive answer.

I've tested with containers with 3 addresses and it seems to work:

```
ccf.setAddresses("host1:5672,host2:5672,host3:5672");
```

However it'll be a lot of work to set up a separate DNS server to return 3 addresses to test.

Comment: This question is more up to RabbitMQ Client by itself: Spring just wraps the one without any extra work around connection options. Consider to share your concern in RabbitMQ mailing list: https://www.rabbitmq.com/contact.html

Comment: Spring seems to add a lot of extra work such as connection recover, and CacheConnectionFactory would turn off rabbitConnectionFactory's auto recovery. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/722fad8ee72a8861a4a2a30c66d9464416c71192/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/connection/CachingConnectionFactory.java#L288. So I believe Spring AMQP/ Spring Rabbit should be the right place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CachingConnectionFactory` exposes an `setAddressResolver(AddressResolver)` option:

```
/**
 * Set an {@link AddressResolver} to use when creating connections; overrides
 * {@link #setAddresses(String)}, {@link #setHost(String)}, and {@link #setPort(int)}.
 * @param addressResolver the resolver.
 * @since 2.1.15
 */
public void setAddressResolver(AddressResolver addressResolver) {
```

One of the impl is probably what you are looking for:

```
/**
 * {@link AddressResolver} that resolves DNS record IPs.
 * Uses {@link InetAddress} internally.
 * The first returned address is used when automatic recovery is NOT enabled
 * at the {@link ConnectionFactory} level.
 * When automatic recovery is enabled, a random address will be picked up
 * from the returned list of {@link Address}es.
 */
public class DnsRecordIpAddressResolver implements AddressResolver {
```

It does this internally `InetAddress.getAllByName(hostName);`

From docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#addressresolver

Comment: But at least you can accept the question, so community will know that here is some solution for similar problems.

Comment: Thanks Artem this is useful. Sorry I don't have enough reputation to upvote yet.
However my question is whether any one option (Addresses, host+port and now AddressResolver) offer any benefits over the other(s).
I suppose DNSRecordIPAddressResolver somewhat simplifies by specifying a single host:port over Addresses (multiple host:port), but I may need to use ListAddressResolver for local tests which negates the benefit.
On the other hand, if using setAddresses, I can unify pretty much all conditions by putting the string in a properties file.
Or are there other benefits I missed?

Comment: Beans can be conditional by the `@Profile`. You just can have a single `AddressResolver` auto-wired into your connection factory. The choice of a proper `AddressResolver` can be dictated by the profile or so. Not sure if a list of addresses in prod is a good choice over DNS resolver...

Comment: Also my apologies for deleting the previous comment because SO did not allow me to edit my comment for more than 5 minutes.

Comment: No problem! It does not allow to any of us. You could just add more comments to follow up.

Comment: By a list of addresses, it could mean:
```
ccf.setAddresses("funny-plum-koala-01.rmq2.cloudamqp.com:5672,funny-plum-koala-02.rmq2.cloudamqp.com:5672,funny-plum-koala-03.rmq2.cloudamqp.com:5672")
or:
ccf.setAddresses("funny-plum-koala.rmq2.cloudamqp.com:5672")
```
There is really no IP addresses listed per se. And it's documented here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#cluster
The strings can also easily be put in properties file and @Value'ed into the applications.

Comment: Yes. That is possible. And why then the question about DNS? If you mean that you got a list of DNS names and you'd like each of them to be resolved to list of their real IPs, then it is not possible out-of-the-box and you probably need to implement your own `CompositeDnsRecordIpAddressResolver`

Comment: I've accepted this answer as it fits my question.